# spark non json to json and to dataframe error

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json type file (not real json structure), but i converted to json and read through spark read json (we are in spark 1.6.0), i can't use multiline feature from spark 2 yet. It displays results , but at the same time it error out. Any help greatly appreciated.

I have document like this .. took just one example, but it is an array :

```
$result = [
            {
              'name' => 'R-2018:1583',
              'issue_date' => '2018-05-17 02:51:06',
              'type' => 'Product Enhancement Advisory', 
              'last_modified_date' => '2018-05-17 03:51:00',
              'id' => 273,
              'update_date' => '2018-05-17 02:51:06',
              'synopsis' => ' enhancement  update',
              'advory' => 'R:1583'
            }
                ]
```

I used like this:

```
jsonRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/xxxx/aa.json").map(lambda x: x[1]).map(lambda x:x.replace('$result =','')).map(lambda x: x.replace("'",'"')).map(lambda x:x.replace("\n","")).map(lambda x:x.replace("=>",":")).map(lambda x:x.replace("  ",""))
sqlContext.read.json(rdd).show()
```

It display the results, but I get the below error also, please help on this.

> 18/08/31 11:19:30 WARN util.ExecutionListenerManager: Error executing query execution listener
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.query.analysis.QueryAnalysis$$anonfun$getInputMetadata$2.apply(QueryAnalysis.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.query.analysis.QueryAnalysis$$anonfun$getInputMetadata$2.apply(QueryAnalysis.scala:108)
>           at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.query.analysis.QueryAnalysis$.getInputMetadata(QueryAnalysis.scala:108)
>           at com.cloudera.spark.lineage.ClouderaNavigatorListener.writeQueryMetadata(ClouderaNavigatorListener.scala:74)
>           at com.cloudera.spark.lineage.ClouderaNavigatorListener.onSuccess(ClouderaNavigatorListener.scala:54)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:100)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:119)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>           at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling(QueryExecutionListener.scala:119)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply$mcV$sp(QueryExecutionListener.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.readLock(QueryExecutionListener.scala:132)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.onSuccess(QueryExecutionListener.scala:98)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2116)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1389)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1471)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:184)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

[json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=json#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json) function take the path of a json file as parameter, so you need to first save the json somewhere and then read this file.

Something like that should work

```
jsonRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/xxxx/aa.json")
            .map(lambda x: x[1])
            .map(lambda x:x.replace('$result =',''))
            .map(lambda x: x.replace("'",'"'))
            .map(lambda x:x.replace("\n",""))
            .map(lambda x:x.replace("=>",":"))
            .map(lambda x:x.replace("  ",""))
            .saveAsTextFile("/user/xxxx/aa_transformed.json") 
sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD).show()
```

Comment: write.json didn't work.. i think it will work only for dataframes. below error message :AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'write'
       However i  used jsonRDD.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/user/xxxx/aa_transformed.json") . It worked great.. Thanks

Comment: Is there way to resolve without writing to file and use in Sqlcontext ?